# Showing a set is disconnected

Tags: real-analysis

I have some homework to show that the metric space of the set $X= [0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is disconnected. That is that there exists some open subsets $O_1$,$O_2$ of $X$ so that $X=O_1\cup O_2$. But I don't understand how the sets $[0,1], [2,3]$ can be open since they contain the boundary points. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: What do the open sets in $X$ look like? (Note, they are not the same as open sets in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: How do you *define* “open” for a subset of $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$?

Comment: Could you use balls of radius $1$ around points $0.25$ and $2.75$ intersected with $X$?

Comment: Following the above comments, you should have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) if you require more clarifications. It happens that your example is cited in this page.